# Disable SharePoint Online Real Time Save on Excel Document

Tags: sharepoint-online, save, excel-online

Is it possible to disable the in browser real time auto save that SharePoint Online has for Excel documents(or any O365 app) that are stored on it? I have a Excel document that I essentially want any time a user goes into it, it is cleared of everything except what was originally there when it was uploaded. Essentially so they can enter in their values in the Excel editor in the browser, snapshot it, close it, and when they come back to it next month it is cleared. Also so that if multiple users have it open in their browser using it all users would NOT see each others changes, in a sense keeping it local to their machine. Then when they close it, it is wiped of what they put in.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, it is better for you to create a template for users in the library. Each time the user just need to create a new file based on it and all there changes will not affect the template. You can specify a custom document template in seconds.

[image]

More information about using template in SharePoint Online:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-a-custom-template-for-a-sharepoint-library-8e0177eb-46bd-4346-9998-330c32733c25